# Tokenizing unsplit words from OCR using NLTK

Tags: python, split, ocr, nltk, tokenize

I'm using NLTK to process some text that is extracted from PDF files. I can recover the text mostly intact, but there are lots of instances where spaces between words are not captured, so I get words like `ifI` instead of `if I`, or `thatposition` instead of `that position`, or `andhe's` instead of `and he's`.

My question is this: how can I use NLTK to look for words it does not recognize/has not learned, and see if there are "nearby" word combinations that are much more likely to occur? Is there a more graceful way to implement this kind of check than simply marching through the unrecognized word, one character at a time, splitting it, and seeing if it makes two recognizable words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you consider using [pyenchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant) instead, since it is a more robust solution for this sort of problem. You can download pyenchant [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/download.html). Here is an example of how you would obtain your results after you install it:

```
>>> text = "IfI am inthat position, Idon't think I will."  # note the lack of spaces
>>> from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
>>> checker = SpellChecker("en_US")
>>> checker.set_text(text)
>>> for error in checker:
    for suggestion in error.suggest():
        if error.word.replace(' ', '') == suggestion.replace(' ', ''):  # make sure the suggestion has exact same characters as error in the same order as error and without considering spaces
            error.replace(suggestion)
            break
>>> checker.get_text()
"If I am in that position, I don't think I will."  # text is now fixed
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, hadn't thought of using a spellchecker. Solution works great, if/when you get pyenchant installed. I had a lot of difficulty installing pyenchant's dependencies (there is no "pip install pyenchant"). Mac binaries on site require Python 2.5 or 2.6, python package index provides binary for Python 2.7 but it requires Homebrew Python. The pyenchant-bidst-osx-sources tarball provided on the website has a Makefile that repeatedly chokes. Ended up installing gettext and glib using Homebrew, & libiconv & enchant from source, then pyenchant with setup.py build/install.

Comment: @charlesreid1 Wow. I'm sorry to hear that the Mac binaries are not up to par. Thanks for noting your process here. Hopefully someone else will find this useful.